# TV film about aliens with clear brain cases and a single eye stalk brainwashing people

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

The film was show on TV prior to the 1980s.

The antagonists were aliens which had a clear brain case and a single eye stalk (similar to the *Dr Who* character; The Brain of Morbius)

They brain wash people by using yellow florescent tubes in boxes (the tubes were a bit like that of *Dr Who*'s terminus but yellow instead of green)

The film was in colour.

Comment: Do you recall any of the following details: Brainwashing victims having mind control powers (their eyes glowed when they used this power)? The first brainwashing victim being a man who was ambushed late at night? The man's wife being suspicious when he started drinking his coffee black? A fall from a great height curing the man's brainwashing (a cloud of brightly coloured vapour emerged from him at this point)? A brainwashed schoolgirl in the final scene, with the voice over "The nightmare is just beginning"?

Comment: Possibly - I was too young to stay up to watch the rest of the film but yeah it rings a bell

Answer (score 1):

The release date isn't an exact match (1980, so not strictly prior to the 1980s), but given that you seem to remember some of the details mentioned in my comment:

- Brainwashing victims having mind control powers (their eyes glowed when they used this power).
- The first brainwashing victim being a man who was ambushed late at night - the fluorescent tubes that you mention appeared in this scene.
- The man's wife being suspicious when he started drinking his coffee black.
- A fall from a great height curing the man's brainwashing (a cloud of brightly coloured vapour emerged from him at this point).
- A brainwashed schoolgirl in the final scene, with the voice over "The nightmare is just beginning".

this could be [The Aliens Are Coming](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080348/).

Comment: Including said details would improve your answer. Adding other details which sound similar to what the OP remembers would aslo help.

Comment: It makes me think of the creatures in 'The Trollenberg Terror"